# Эхо клиент сервер

Tags: java, c#, сокет, socket.io

Здравствуйте, реализую клиент-сервер по типу-эхо: клиент каждые 10 секунд шлет пакет серверу, а тот отвечает. Если нужно отрубить клиента, то все нормально, нет ни запроса, ни ответа на сервере, сервер просто слушает, пока клиент не пришлет что-нибудь. Но если отрубается сервер-программа, то клиент все равно шлет пакеты даже не дожидаясь ответа, так как при запуске повторно сервера в логе накапливаются запоздалые пакеты разом, которые накопились за время пока сервер был выключен. Как это исключить?

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Answer (score 0):

```
           static public void mythread2()
         {
        //IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
        // IPAddress ipAddr = 
        IPAddress.Parse("192.168.42.102");/////////////////////////
        ///

        IPAddress ipAddr = 
         IPAddress.Parse("192.168.42.102");/////////////////////////


        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7712);




            // Создаем сокет Tcp/Ip
            sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Назначаем сокет локальной конечной точке и слушаем входящие сокеты
            try
            {
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(1);


            // Начинаем слушать соединения


         while (true)
              {




               Socket handler = sListener.Accept();




                // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение

                data = null;



                // Мы дождались клиента, пытающегося с нами соединиться


            byte[] bytes = new byte[handler.ReceiveBufferSize];
          int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);


            data += Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

               Console.WriteLine(data);

              //string TT = "888";
                // byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TT);

                byte[] msg = new byte[2];

                msg[0] = 0x2;
                msg[1] = 0x3;



                //handler.Send(Message);

                handler.Send(msg);




               handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
               handler.Close();




            }



        }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            sListener.Close();
        }
            finally
            {

            }



    }
```

Comment: Выше клиент на Java, ниже на С# СЕРВЕР